# Why is clock_nanosleep sleeping for 20 ms when it is configured to sleep for 10 ms?

Tags: linux-kernel, posix

I am trying to run a task periodically every 10 ms. Before executing the task, I want to check the consistency of `clock_nanosleep`. I took 10 values to check the time `clock_nanosleep` is sleeping, but they are varying in between 19-22 ms, which should be 10 ms.

I am running this thread with SCHED_FIFO, pri-98, with HRTimers enabled in Linux. Currently, I am using 3.14.29 Linux Kernel with RT Patch. Does `clock_nanosleep` require any extra configuration in Linux apart from HRTIMERS?

Below is the code snippet that I am running:

```
struct timespec arr[20];
while(1) {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&check1);
    if(i<20) {
        arr[i].tv_sec = check1.tv_sec;
        arr[i].tv_nsec = check1.tv_nsec;
        ++i;
    }
    check1.tv_nsec += p_CT->period;

    clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, TIMER_ABSTIME, &check1, NULL);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&check);
    if(i<20) {
        arr[i].tv_sec = check.tv_sec;
        arr[i].tv_nsec = check.tv_nsec;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `p_CT->period`?

Comment: Also result of `clock_getres` could be interested - which resolution is actual for the clock.

Comment: Hi Roman Zaytsev p_CT->period = 10000; for 10msec periodicity

Comment: Hi Tsyvarev 9 , i ran clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&timeb);             it returned with nano second resolution.                                        printf("resolution = %lld.%.9ld ",(long long)(timeb.tv_sec),(long )(timeb.tv_nsec));                                                                                  resolution = 0.000000001

Comment: What is the timer frequency configured with your kernel (`zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_HZ.*y`)?  Are you using an HPET?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong data, i checked for 10microseconds instead of 10milliseconds, and there is difference 0f (9-10micro seconds) for clock_nanosleep, it can be caused because of clock_gettime(..) or other api usage. my task is being called for every 10msec with little difference in micro seconds.

Answer (score 0):

- check return values of `clock_gettime` and `clock_nanosleep`. Maybe there was interruption by signal
- run two sequenced `clock_gettime` and calculate average execution time of `clock_gettime`. I don't think that it will be around 9-12ms, but let's check

Code:

```
int r1 = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&check1);
int r2 = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&check);  
if(i<20) {  
    arr[i].tv_sec = check1.tv_sec;  
    arr[i].tv_nsec = check1.tv_nsec;  
    ++i;  
}  
if(i<20) {  
    arr[i].tv_sec = check.tv_sec;  
    arr[i].tv_nsec = check.tv_nsec;  
    ++i;  
}  
printf("%d %d\n", r1, r2);
```